# How to dynamically import and instantiate classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributeerror

I have an app which requires some complex information validation. Validations (in the form of Python classes) will constantly be added and tweaked as the team grows alongside the complexity. Hence, I'm trying to come up with a clean way of eventually just dynamically processing all of the validation Python classes from a master `validator.py` file.

My attempt so far is yielding a nice `AttributeError`.

That said, my project structure is:

```
validator

    validators
        census_data.py
        ethnicity.py
        financials.py

    __init__.py
    validator.py
```

Within my `validator.py` file I have the following code:

```py
class Validator:

    validators = ['validator.validators.financials']

    def run(self):
        for validator in self.validators:
            module = __import__(validator)

            # Haven't implemented the dynamic split of the class name yet
            validator_class = getattr(module, 'Financials')
            validator_class.run()
```

Within the `financials.py` file I have the following:

```py
class Financials:

    def run(self):
        return True
```

When I trigger the `validator.py` file through a test I get the following error:

```
AttributeError module 'validator' has no attribute 'Financials'
```

Comment: The `validators = ['validator.validators.financials']` statement create a list with one string in it, which is causing the `AttributeError` (`validators` is a `list` object).

Comment: I suggest looking at Django source code and just borrow some solution. There is one I really like [module_loading](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7e6b214ed34f5562dbd83cf54924a5b589a29715/django/utils/module_loading.py) . The main point is using the `importlib` to make the dynamic imports. And it does, what you probably exactly describe.